# Is it Possible to Use jQuery UI *Without* the Colors?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I jut recently tried to upgrade jQuery UI, and after I did I was shocked to find that it completely changed the look of my site.  I'd like to use the jQuery UI *logic*, and I'd like to have whatever minimal CSS is needed to (say) make a dialog have the right dimensions, but I don't want any of jQuery UI's fonts/colors/backgrounds/etc.

Is there any way to get a CSS file like that?  I tried playing around with the theme roller, but it seems to assume I want styles for some color and some font, when I don't want any at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root directory of a jQuery UI download zip should include `jquery-ui.structure.css` which contains just the structural CSS without any of the themeing.  You may have to add some of your own styles on top of that to get a usable UI.

Comment: Unfortunately `jquery-ui.structure.css` doesn't actually contain the CSS for the structure of dialogs/autocompletes, which means I have to re-create it by hand.  However, that's still a lot better than trying to fix all of the visual styles that the main CSS files include.  Why the jQuery UI devs felt the need to conflate colors/fonts with positions and dimensions is beyond me, but at least this way I have less to fix; thanks!